Newsletter box's "Love this site?" header, and all edit help boxes, should be headers instead of divs
Description
The community digest/newsletter advertisement, which doesn't always appear, misuses the s-sidebarwidget--header class to imitate the appearance of a header without header markup. The "Love this site?" header is simply inside a <div> with that class. As previously pointed out, the Stacks design system requires s-sidebarwidget--header to be added to "appropriate" headers:

The examples of s-sidebarwidget--header are shown shown [sic] added to h2 elements in examples, but the appropriate heading level may differ depending on context. Please use the appropriate heading level for the context to ensure heading levels only increase by 1.

There's a typo duplicating "shown" which is out of scope for this post.
Additionally, as I said before, inappropriate use of header styling sans header markup is an accessibility issue. A screen reader would be unable to know that "Love this site?" should be a header. The page's markup is lying.
This exact issue (giving a <div> the s-sidebarwidget--header class) appears in at least all these places:

Community digest advertisement's "Love this site?"
"How to Edit" (note: there's no "How to Tag")
"How to Format"
"What are Tag Wikis?"

I suspect this issue exists in all the edit help boxes where dinguses were used instead of <li>s, which would also include moderator private messages and "Describe why you would make a good moderator", but I can't actually check those.
Appearance

Code
<div id="newsletter-ad" class="s-sidebarwidget mb16">
    <div class="s-sidebarwidget--header">
        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon iconMail" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18"><path d="m1 6 8 5 8-5V4L9 9 1 4c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h12c1.09 0 2 .91 2 2v10c0 1.09-.91 2-2 2H3c-1.09 0-2-.91-2-2z"></path></svg> Love this site?
    </div>
    <div class="s-sidebarwidget--content d-block">

        <p id="newsletter-ad-header">Get the <b>weekly newsletter!</b> In it, you'll get:</p>
        <ul>
            <li>The week's top questions and answers</li>
            <li>Important community announcements</li>
            <li>Questions that need answers</li>
        </ul>
    <div id="newsletter-signup-container" class="ta-center">
        <button id="newsletter-signup" class="s-btn s-btn__filled">Sign up for the digest</button>
    </div>
    <p id="newsletter-preview-container" class="mt8 mb0 ta-center">see an <a href="/digest/preview" id="newsletter-preview">example newsletter</a></p>

    </div>
</div>


Apologies for expanding the feature request a half hour after it was created. I only noticed the other locations a couple minutes ago. Since it's the same issue I figured I could just list all the places.

Additionally, subheaders (e.g. "Other suggestions" in "Step 2: Review your question") don't use subheader markup. They're just <div>s again, this time styled with the class js-guidance-title: <div class="js-guidance-title">Other suggestions</div>
